# Get many words in one search and display. in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, string

I have a php script which searches a user input word and displays the result, but I need to enable it to search more than one word and to display it.

The words are saved in a database.

Now my code accepts only `"word1"`to be replaced to `"word2"`.

I need to make it `"word1"` to be replaced to `"word2" + "word3" to "word4"` and as many as user types.

Here is my current PHP code:

```
function Search() {

    $q = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE word_title = '" . str_replace('_', ' ', addslashes($_GET['word'])) . "';";
    $res = mysql_query($q);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        $c.= '' . LNtoBR($row['word_desc']) . '';
    }
    $GLOBALS['content'].= $c;
    $GLOBALS['content'].= '';
}
```

I tried like this:

```
function Search() {

    $q = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE word_title = '" . str_replace('_', ' ', addslashes($_GET['word'])) . "';";
    $res = mysql_query($q);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        $c.= 'explode(' . LNtoBR($row['word_desc']) . '), implode(' . LNtoBR($row['word_desc']) . ')';
    }
    $GLOBALS['content'].= $c;
    $GLOBALS['content'].= '';
}
```

but it doesn't works like JavaScript accepts `split(something).join(something);` but I need to get the strings from the database and to replace all the user searched string lines with any word that is existing in my database. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't quite get you, can you be more clear on what is required?

Comment: thanks for the quick response. this is the page I am editing "http://raadso.so/translate/" just write one word like "fiican" it will replace it to"good" but i need it to replace like "fiican fiican fiican" to "good good good" and the above code is the one i used for this page script which php.

Comment: When I write more than word, it doesn't display anything. For example if I write 'fiican fiican'.

Comment: @HeroFTime this code returns only one word per search, but I need to make search more words like "good good good" to "fiican fiican fiican" thanks

Comment: I’m curious as to what the line inside the while loop, that concatenates the _string_ values `'explode(…), implode(…)'` into a variable is supposed to achieve …?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't make comments yet.

Use PHP [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for searching and replacing your words.

Also check out PHP [nl2br](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) instead of the function you are using (LNtoBR).

Comment: thanks but can't fix this yet, I will update if I get solution for it.